# Who is the biological father of this character in the Broken Earth Trilogy?

Tags: broken-earth

I just finished the *Broken Earth* Trilogy and was waiting for a reveal related to this. Maybe I missed it, but:

Do we know for sure that

> Jija is Nassun's biological father?

It seems to me that

> the timing would line up for either Alabaster or Innon to be bio-dad, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It's Jija

N. K. Jemisin gives us enough information for a definitive answer. Right after the climactic event in *The Fifth Season* we see

> Her fellow survivors will find her and take her to the mainland.  There she will wander, lost and losing herself, ***for two long years***.

If it is not Jija, it's also not Alabaster or Innon. Connect this with the beginning,  where we see

> You're an orogene who's been living in the little nothing town of Tirimo for ten years...Jija's a man Tirimo born and bred, a stoneknapper of the Resistant use-caste...

And then, at the very beginning of *The Obelisk Gate*,

> Nassun next, then. Nassun ***who is just eight years old*** when the world ends.

Had Nassun been someone else's child than Jija's, Essun would have had to have had an affair with some unknown man in the little town of Tirimo, and this never appears in the trilogy at all.

N. K. Jemisin is too good an author to insert a pair of unfired [Chekhov's pistols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov's_gun) like that.

Also note that Nassun has (had) a little brother, Uche, who might have been even a stronger orogene than her.

Essun's character growth in the story is driven by her decision to stop letting things happen to her, and do things herself.

> But this really begins only after she finds Uche's body.

Comment: Additionally, the fact that she's Jija's biological child saves her from being murdered in panic and rage like Uche just before: "Her eyes jerk up to him, rather than staying on Uche's body, which saves her life. The gray color of her eyes is her mother's, but the shape of her face is Jija's. Just the sight of her pulls him a step away from the primal panic into which he has decended." (early in "The Obelisk Gate")